# Passing parameters in Static SQL query in .module file - Drupal 8

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

In my Drupal 8 site I am having a 'Search' page functionality. For this I am trying to join my custom SQL query with core Drupal search query. I am trying to add parameters to the SQL query in the .module file and it's throwing me syntax error. My query is as below:

```
function mymodule_views_query_alter(\Drupal\views\ViewExecutable $view, \Drupal\views\Plugin\views\query\QueryPluginBase $query) {
//If my view is my-search and the Miles field is not empty and not 'Any' and zipcode field is not empty

  $searched_miles_value = $view->getRequest()->get('field_miles_value');
  $searched_zip_value = $view->getRequest()->get('field_zip_value');

  if(!empty($searched_miles_value)) {
    _remove_view_query_condition($query, 'node__field_miles.field_miles_value');
  } 

  if(!empty($searched_zip_value)) {
    _remove_view_query_condition($query, 'node__field_zip.field_zip_value');
  }

  if($view->id() == 'my_search'  && 
      !empty($searched_miles_value) &&
      !empty($searched_zip_value) &&
      ($searched_miles_value != 'any')) {

        $connection = \Drupal\Core\Database\Database::getConnection();
        $result = $connection->query('SELECT to_zip FROM zipmaster_xref WHERE from_zip = [field_zip_value] AND miles = [field_miles_value]')->fetchAll();

        $target_zips = ['98567'];//hardcoded for testing
        foreach($result as $zip) {
          $target_zips[] = $zip->to_zip;
        }

        $query->addWhere('new_group', 'node__field_zip.field_zip_value', $target_zips, 'IN');
  }
```

I am getting syntax error on the SQL query line. Any help to fox this?

Comment: what is the error??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use variables in query:

```
$result = $connection->query("SELECT to_zip FROM zipmaster_xref WHERE from_zip = '".$searched_zip_value."' AND miles = '".$searched_miles_value."'")->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is working fine. Atleast I'm not seeing the error :)